# Working days SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem I can't get my head around.

I have a table of events and a table of users.  Some events are chargeable and some are not.  What I want to establish is the number chargeable days per week month and year for every user.

Here is the data...

```
ID FromDate    ToDate       isChargeable     Username
1  2014-11-03  2014-11-04        Y           AUser 
2  2014-11-04  2014-11-06        Y           AUser
3  2014-11-07  2014-11-07        Y           AUser
```

And I've written a basic query to calculate the difference between the from and to dates and sum them adding 1 to the total as the toDate counts as a full day.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FromDate, ToDate, isChargeable,Username, DATEDIFF(day, FromDate, ToDate) + 1) AS 'count1'
FROM            dbo.vDiary
GROUP BY FromDate, ToDate, isChargeable,Username
```

This results in...

```
      FromDate    ToDate       isChargeable     Username   count1
      2014-11-03  2014-11-04        Y           AUser      2
      2014-11-04  2014-11-06        Y           AUser      3
      2014-11-07  2014-11-07        Y           AUser      1
```

Which is incorrect as it's showing 6 working days because two events are overlapping.

How can I allow for this overlapping?  I need to state that if there is an event on a particular day that is chargeable then that day is a chargeable day.

I think I need a calendar table but I'm not sure on the process of using it to get the right results.

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Thanks

Steve

EDIT: Trying solution from below

```
        ;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY Username ORDER BY FromDate) rn,
                FromDate,ToDate,isChargeable,Username
         FROM   #calen)
SELECT a.FromDate,a.ToDate,a.isChargeable,a.Username,
       CASE
         WHEN a.FromDate > b.ToDate
               OR b.ToDate IS NULL THEN Datediff(day, a.FromDate, a.ToDate) + 1
         ELSE Datediff(day, Dateadd(dd, 1, b.ToDate), a.ToDate)+ 1
       END DatDiff,
       *
FROM   cte a
       LEFT JOIN cte b
              ON a.rn = b.rn + 1
                 AND a.username = b.username
WHERE  ( a.ToDate > b.todate
          OR b.ToDate IS NULL )
```

Produces (updated)

```
FromDate    ToDate  isChargeable    Username    DatDiff rn  FromDate    ToDate  isChargeable    Username    rn  FromDate    ToDate  isChargeable    Username
2014-11-03  2014-11-04  Y   AUser                2      1   2014-11-03  2014-11-04  Y   AUser   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2014-11-04  2014-11-06  Y   AUser                2      2   2014-11-04  2014-11-06  Y   AUser   1   2014-11-03  2014-11-04  Y   AUser
2014-11-07  2014-11-07  Y   AUser                1      3   2014-11-07  2014-11-07  Y   AUser   2   2014-11-04  2014-11-06  Y   AUser
2014-12-03  2014-12-15  Y   AUser                13     4   2014-12-03  2014-12-15  Y   AUser   3   2014-11-07  2014-11-07  Y   AUser
2014-12-10  2014-12-17  Y   AUser                2      5   2014-12-10  2014-12-17  Y   AUser   4   2014-12-03  2014-12-15  Y   AUser
2015-12-04  2015-12-15  Y   AUser                12     6   2015-12-04  2015-12-15  Y   AUser   5   2014-12-10  2014-12-17  Y   AUser
2014-11-03  2014-11-03  Y   BUser                1      1   2014-11-03  2014-11-03  Y   BUser   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2014-11-04  2014-11-04  Y   BUser                1      2   2014-11-04  2014-11-04  Y   BUser   1   2014-11-03  2014-11-03  Y   BUser
```

Comment: You are "done in" by your own rule that ToDate = 1 full day. That's why you're seeing what you're seeing. If the 2nd entry is for the same event, then change your code to write the record in where max(Todate) of previous entry + 1 = FromDate for the same event for the 2nd day. ie, it should say 2014-11-05, not 04

Comment: Perhaps read about **[gaps & islands](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)** to piece together the sequential parts and eliminate the extra days.

Comment: Why all ID have same value 1. Or Is  it 1,2,3

Comment: I've changed the IDs to be unique.  Sorry about that

Comment: @user3036342 - I can't change the code / rules.  The data already exists.  I'm just trying to make sense of it.

Comment: If `ToDate` is inclusive then `FromDate` must not overlap. You should fix your data.

Comment: If those 3 records are for the same event, then you could do a min/max on the dates to get a "real" to/from count that's chargeable?

Comment: They are all different events unfortunately.  E.g. a person could be doing one meeting in the morning and one in the afternoon.  They are different events but only 1 chargeable day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

If you have Unique ID's try this.

```
create table #calen(ID int, FromDate   date, ToDate date,isChargeable char(1),Username varchar(20))

INSERT #calen
VALUES (1,'2014-11-03','2014-11-04','Y ','AUser'),
       (2,'2014-11-04','2014-11-06','Y','AUser'),
       (3,'2014-11-07','2014-11-07','Y','AUser') 


SELECT a.FromDate,a.ToDate,a.isChargeable,a.Username,
       CASE
         WHEN a.FromDate > b.ToDate
               OR b.ToDate IS NULL THEN Datediff(day, a.FromDate, a.ToDate) + 1
         ELSE Datediff(day, Dateadd(dd, 1, b.ToDate), a.ToDate)
              + 1
       END DatDiff
FROM   #calen a
       LEFT JOIN #calen b
              ON a.id = b.id + 1
WHERE  ( a.ToDate > b.todate
          OR b.ToDate IS NULL )
```

**Update :**

For more than one user.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY Username ORDER BY FromDate) rn,
                FromDate,ToDate,isChargeable,Username
         FROM   #calen)
SELECT a.FromDate,a.ToDate,a.isChargeable,a.Username,
       CASE
         WHEN a.FromDate > b.ToDate
               OR b.ToDate IS NULL THEN Datediff(day, a.FromDate, a.ToDate) + 1
         ELSE Datediff(day, Dateadd(dd, 1, b.ToDate), a.ToDate)+ 1
       END DatDiff
FROM   cte a
       LEFT JOIN cte b
              ON a.rn = b.rn + 1
                 AND a.username = b.username
WHERE  ( a.ToDate > b.todate
          OR b.ToDate IS NULL )
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
FromDate    ToDate      isChargeable    Username    DatDiff
----------  ----------  ------------    --------    -------
2014-11-03  2014-11-04  Y               AUser           2
2014-11-04  2014-11-06  Y               AUser           2
2014-11-07  2014-11-07  Y               AUser           1
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm having issues though when I add extra users...   (see edit above)

Comment: @SteveMcCall Where above?? I don see any new users in your question !!

Comment: BUser instead of AUser (not very imaginative I'm afraid)

Comment: insert into #user values(4,'2014-12-03',    '2014-12-15',        'Y',           'AUser')
insert into #user values(5,'2015-12-04',    '2015-12-15',        'Y',           'AUser')
insert into #user values(6,'2014-12-10',    '2014-12-17',        'Y',          'AUser') Try adding these values and check your query

Comment: That's looking pretty good to me so far.  I'll run some data though it and check back later.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2be3c/3 You query failed when overlapping. How a user work for -1 day.

Comment: Yes @Veera you are correct, it doesn't seem to handle those values.

Comment: @Veera - Check now dude.

Comment: Hi @NoDisplayName.  Thanks for this, please see my above edit as I'm still getting some anomalies

Comment: @SteveMcCall - Removed the unwanted columns.Check now updated

Comment: @NoDisplayName - Still the same results.  Showing 2 days between 2014-12-10 & 2014-12-17 instead of 8

Comment: @SteveMcCall - Yes man because it is overlapping with this date `2014-12-03 to 2014-12-15` so after 15 - 17 only two days.

Comment: @NoDisplayName Right ok, I get that.  I should have put together better data for testing.  Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

If all the ID values are not unique we can have the below query:

```
SELECT ID, FromDate, ToDate, isChargeable, Username,
 CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT ToDate FROM UserTable B WHERE A.FromDate = B.ToDate 
   AND A.UserName = B.UserName AND A.ID <> B.ID) THEN
   DATEDIFF(day, FromDate, ToDate)
 ELSE
   DATEDIFF(day, FromDate, ToDate) + 1
 END  AS 'count1'
FROM UserTable A
```

else we have to create CTE to create unique ROWID.

```
;WITH UserTable
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY FromDate) RowID,
                FromDate,ToDate, isChargeable, Username
         FROM #user)

SELECT RowID, FromDate, ToDate, isChargeable, Username,
 CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT ToDate FROM UserTable B WHERE A.FromDate = B.ToDate 
       AND A.UserName = B.UserName AND A.RowID <> B.RowID) THEN
   DATEDIFF(day, FromDate, ToDate)
 ELSE
   DATEDIFF(day, FromDate, ToDate) + 1
 END  AS 'count1'
FROM UserTable A
```

Comment: Why you need Distinct and Group by

Comment: Try inserting these dates `(4,'2014-12-03','2014-12-15','Y ','AUser'),(5,'2014-12-10','2014-12-17','Y ','AUser')` and check your query

Comment: Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a9f2/2 You query failed when overlapping is more than one day

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT a.* ,y.flag
FROM EventsTable a
OUTER APPLY 
  (SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, a.ToDate, x.FromDate) as flag 
  FROM EventsTable x 
  WHERE a.id = x.id AND x.FromDate > a.ToDate) y)

SELECT id,FromDate,ToDate,isChargeable,Username,
   CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN 
      DATEDIFF(dd, FromDate, ToDate) 
   ELSE DATEDIFF(dd, FromDate,ToDate) + 1 
   END AS count1
FROM CTE
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem as you can still get 6 working days in a 5 day week.

Comment: This produces 2 days for 03-04, 3 days for 04-06 and 1 day for 07-07.  That's 6 days for one week.  The problem is the overlapping of days.  I think a calendar table might be needed.